# Layers misaligned in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, sar, nitf

I have two National Imagery Transmission Format Standard (NITF) files loaded into QGIS 3.10 and they should be the same coordinate system but for some reason I cannot figure why they are not aligned.

**Steps to recreate:**

1) Loaded the following [NITFs files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d6d3ds8nqv7kxw4/AABTID18BqB48o0L_dZo-tOPa?dl=0) into QGIS. One image is synthetic aperture radar and the other is electro-optical imagery.

2) Layers do not align:[image]

3) I loaded both files into GDAL in python and printed out the result of `GetProjection()` and got the same result for both:

`GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]`

**Additional info:**

Dataset is from this data source: https://github.com/AFRL-RY/data-unicorn-2008

**Edit:**

This is the .prj file I get when use QGIS after loading the images (Raster>Projections>Extract Project) rather than use python GDAL's getProjection()

`GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

I tried changing to the different CRS's as suggested the misaligned SAR image either stayed the same or disappeared (probably incorrectly projected somewhere else on the globe). Some of the EPSGs were not present in the options in QGIS.

I set a basemap and we see that the EO image is aligned but the SAR seems rotated.

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or is it a bit odd that the projection lists 5 separate EPSG codes? Maybe try changing the CRS of one of the images to EPSG:7030, EPSG:6325, EPSG:9801, or EPSG:9122 and see if any of them look right. Also, add a basemap to your project so you can see if either of the images is oriented correctly.

Comment: I tried the suggestions but they were still misaligned. The projections I extracted via QGIS seems to be different from the GDAL's output. I also included an image along with a basemap and it looks like EO is correctly aligned but the SAR isn't. Any suggestions on what to try next would be appreciated.

Comment: @csk those are standard EPSG codes for projection support entities, e.g. `unit: degree` ([EPSG:9122](https://epsg.io/9122-units)); that whole wkt string (extracted from GDAL) corresponds with the *proj4* definition of EPSG:4326 (`SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srtext = '<wkt_string>'`)

Comment: `gdalinfo` lists a `GeoTransform` property on the SAR r5 file; this transformation array is applied to the projection...see if that is the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the axis orientation of the SAR file. If you run gdalinfo on it, you get:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -84.0569550,  39.8130372) ( 84d 3'25.04"W, 39d48'46.93"N)
Lower Left  ( -84.1260450,  39.8130372) ( 84d 7'33.76"W, 39d48'46.93"N)
Upper Right ( -84.0569550,  39.7559628) ( 84d 3'25.04"W, 39d45'21.47"N)
Lower Right ( -84.1260450,  39.7559628) ( 84d 7'33.76"W, 39d45'21.47"N)
```

which is wrong because the left longitude coordinates should be the same unless the image is rotated. So if you create a VRT file around it with

```
gdal_translate -of vrt -a_ullr  -84.1260450 39.8130372 -84.0569550 39.7559628 SAR.ntf.r5 SAR.vrt
```

You get an image that gets placed correctly in QGIS:

[image]